# Python classes implemetation difficulties

Tags: python, class

Every time that I try to run this code in the python idle it says that my indentation is incorrect, and I have done numerous alterations to try to get it running, none of which worked. Any advice you could give me to get it working?

```
from random import randint
class enemy:
    def __init__(self, type, bhealth, dmglvl):
        self.type = type
        self.bhealth = int(bhealth)
        self.dmglvl = int(dmglvl)
        enhealth=self.bhealth
    def eninfo(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.type, self.bhealth, self.dmglvl)
    def battleintro(self):
        return 'an enemy {} has appeared! \nIt has: {} health.'.format(self.type, self.bhealth)
    def hit(self):
        print('You swing your sword at the {}.'.format(self.type))
        chardmg=randint(8,15)
        enhealth-=chardmg
        print('You deal {} damage. The {} has {} hit-points left.'.format(chardmg, self.type, enhealth))
        if enhealth <=1:
            return 'The {} Died!'.format(self.type)
enemy1 = enemy("goblin", 15, 1)
print(enemy1.eninfo())
print(enemy1.battleintro())
```

Comment: Yes: use PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/. It could be that you're mixing tabs and spaces for example. But could be something else. PyCharm will guide you and will help to get rid of those silly errors.

Comment: Here `enhealth` goes out of the scope. In `__init__` make it `self.enhealth`

Comment: If you are using a text editor like Notepad++ you can try doing search-and-replace on `\t` (a tab character) with four spaces.

Comment: the code you posted here works without problems. You might want to copy the code from the question into your file and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you typing this as a file, or are yu trying to type this directly into the interactive interpreter - the default screen when idle opens up?

The interactive intrepreter is meant for testing and short code sequences, not for one to try to type entire classes - but overall, it does have some key differences to what you can type in an actual program file: the most proemminent being that at the end of a code block you have to skip a line (i.e. an extra blank line) - otherwise it will give you an error.

So you'd have to include a whiteine before your "enmey1 = ..." line - but rather, you have to type it as a "myfile.py" file, not in the interpreter, and afterwards run it with "import myfile" to test it interactively.